# Why is Facebook referenced in TrustFrameworkBase.xml?

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/tutorial-create-user-flows?pivots=b2c-custom-policy) for Azure AD B2C says "Base file - Few modifications are required to the base". I expected to change just the TenantId and PublicPolicyUri at the beginning of the file.

I was surprised to find that a Facebook ClaimsProvider is defined in the base file. Shouldn't that be in TrustFrameworkExtensions.xml? If I don't want to use Facebook, I have to make lots of changes to TrustFrameworkBase.xml.

I got my TrustFrameworkBase.xml from the SocialAccounts folder of the [start pack](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-custom-policy-starterpack) GitHub repository that is referenced in the documentation. Is there a better place to get a TrustFrameworkBase file?

Comment: The best place to get the starter pack is the [ief setup tool](https://aka.ms/iefsetup), just select “Remove Facebook references”

Answer (score 0):

Facebook is there because it is a social account and it shows how to integrate one.

Use [local accounts](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-custom-policy-starterpack/tree/main/LocalAccounts).

Comment: Yeah, it shows you how to integrate one but isn't putting it in TrustFrameworkBase showing you the wrong way to do it?

Comment: I don't do it that way. I use a separate extension file. But some people like everything in one place. I don't advise that. I leave the Base alone so it's easy to merge in updates. But it's been like that in the starter pack since day 1.